# why do i see vuetify css in view source?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I use nuxt.js with vuetify. the website works great and already in production. but when i look at view source, i see lots of garbage, that i would prefer to avoid, mainly for performance reasons. the culprit is vuetify, that spits what looks like all available colors, whether i use them or not. here is a very small portion of this:

```
.v-application .primary {
  background-color: #1976d2 !important;
  border-color: #1976d2 !important;
}
.v-application .primary--text {
  color: #1976d2 !important;
  caret-color: #1976d2 !important;
}
.v-application .primary.lighten-5 {
  background-color: #c7fdff !important;
  border-color: #c7fdff !important;
}
.v-application .primary--text.text--lighten-5 {
  color: #c7fdff !important;
  caret-color: #c7fdff !important;
}
.v-application .primary.lighten-4 {
  background-color: #a8e0ff !important;
  border-color: #a8e0ff !important;
}
.v-application .primary--text.text--lighten-4 {
  color: #a8e0ff !important;
  caret-color: #a8e0ff !important;
}
```

it goes on and on like this.
and this is after production build. Any idea how to remove this?

Answer (score 2):

[@Ron Al](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1941285/ron-al)
you can add this as your default purge-css config for nuxt.
So, in your **nuxt.config.js** add

```
purgeCSS: {
    enabled: true,
    paths: [
      'components/**/*.vue',
      'layouts/**/*.vue',
      'pages/**/*.vue',
      'plugins/**/*.js',
      './node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js'
    ],
    styleExtensions: ['.css'],
    // whitelist: ['body', 'html', 'nuxt-progress', ''],

    whitelist: ['v-application', 'v-application--wrap','layout','row','col'],
    whitelistPatterns: [
      /^v-((?!application).)*$/,
      /^theme--*/,
      /.*-transition/,
      /^justify-*/,
      /^p*-[0-9]/,
      /^m*-[0-9]/,
      /^text--*/,
      /--text$/,
      /^row-*/,
      /^col-*/
    ],
    whitelistPatternsChildren: [/^v-((?!application).)*$/, /^theme--*/],

    extractors: [
      {
        extractor: content => content.match(/[A-z0-9-:\\/]+/g) || [],
        extensions: ['html', 'vue', 'js']
      }
    ]
  }
```

Got it from this website:
https://qiita.com/nogutk/items/58370cd8a713111be9bc

**Furthermore**, you can whitelist any css that you don't want to be purged by surrounding it in special css comments
`/* purgecss start ignore */` and
`/* purgecss end ignore */`
as shown below

```
<style>
/* purgecss start ignore */

some_class {
  text-transform: none !important;
}

/* purgecss end ignore */
</style>
```

Comment: Using this and icons: 'mdi' still doesn't purge the size of the 300kb icons, any idea why? @Ambassel

Comment: I didn't use purgecss for that, I simply selected mdi icons manually... added only 30 mdi icons with {icons: mdi, values: someObject}... and used them as <v-icon>$vuetify.icons.mdiPhone</v-icon>

Comment: Didn't that create massive problems for you when every single component which needs icons, e.g combobox, v-select etc. doesn't have their icons & you have to find ways to add them manually? Any chance you can link a codepen example?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **nuxt-purgecss** to remove all **unused css**.

you can simply add it in the **buildModules** section of your nuxt.config.js as shown below.

[nuxt-purgecss](https://purgecss.com/guides/nuxt.html)

Comment: thanks. that thing destroyed my website, so i had to remove it. looking for more options. I wonder what's the built in, the 'by-the-book' solution for deploying a nuxt+vuetify solution.